# React: How to pass data into the "useDrop" function?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following react component

```js
export default function AssetDropZone({ testVal }) {
    console.log(testVal); //this one works

    const [{ canDrop, isOver, isDragging }, onDropTarget] = useDrop({
      accept: [ItemTypes.File],
      drop(item) {
        console.log(testVal) //this one returns undefined
      },
      collect: monitor => ({
        canDrop: monitor.canDrop(),
        isOver: monitor.isOver(),
        isDragging: monitor.getItem() !== null && monitor.canDrop()
      })
    });
}
```

I'm trying to get `testVal` to print when the `drop()` method executes, however every time I run it the value of `testVal` is `undefined`.

I know other react functions like `useCallback()` have the option to pass in an array of variables you want to use in the function, however when I try to do the same with this it doesn't seem to have any effect.

I've double checked that `testVal` is defined, but I'm currently at a loss as to what's happening. Anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Can you show whatever is using `AssetDropZone`? Seems like whatever it using `AssetDropZone` is passing in undefined for `testVal`.

Comment: I edited the original post to show that it is, in fact defined. If I print the value outside of the `useDrop()` function call, then it prints correctly, if I print it inside then it's undefined. It seems to be some kind of scope issue, but I have no idea how to get around this

Comment: `AssetDropZone()` component might be called more than once. Is it called with `undefined` any times in the future? Either that or accidentally setting `testVal` to undefined later are the only reasons it could "magically change values".

Comment: Nope, only printing a single time to the console and using VS Code's search it doesn't seem be used anywhere else other than the one time I'm using it for. Like I said in OP, I ran into a similar problem with `useCallBack()` where there was a way to pass in an array of variables, but `useDrop` _says_ it works this way, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/api/use-drop This claims that it accepts a dependencies array just like `useMemo` or `useCallback` or whatnot. Just to verify, have you added specific labels to the console.logs (e.g. `console.log('First test val', testVal)`) to verify that it's never undefined in the first one?

Comment: Have you tried instead of `console.log(testVal)` to do `() => console.log(testVal)`?

Comment: Figured it out. There was another component by a different name (which was the one I actually wanted) which was somehow triggering the events of the one I was modifying by mistake. Frustrating, but it works now. Thanks for rubber ducking